# registerUserNotificationSettings user feedback?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swift2

Is there a possibility to get feedback or a callback from registerUserNotificationSettings?

I will only ask for permission if the user clicks the notification button, but I don't want him to tap it twice to actually enable the notification.

Something like:

```
if registerUserNotificationSettings.success {
    saveNotification()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `application(_:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:)` in your app delegate.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings settings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    // check for success here
}
```

> Apps that use local or remote notifications to alert the user to new
>   information must register the types of notifications they want to use
>   by calling the registerUserNotificationSettings: method of the app
>   object. The system compares your app’s request with the user’s
>   preferences to determine the types of local and remote notifications
>   allowed, and returns the results to your app by calling this method.
>   Check the contents of the notificationSettings parameter whenever this
>   method is called.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement following method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
```

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:):

> Apps that use local or remote notifications to alert the user to new
>   information must register the types of notifications they want to use
>   by calling the registerUserNotificationSettings: method of the app
>   object. The system compares your app’s request with the user’s
>   preferences to determine the types of local and remote notifications
>   allowed, and returns the results to your app by calling this method.
>   Check the contents of the notificationSettings parameter whenever this
>   method is called.

Comment: Thanks for your help!